# How are QGLWidget's glXXX function calls handled?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

How does Qt handle the function calls to various OpenGL functions such as glVertex3f in a QGLWidget?

Are these calls part of the QGLWidget object or are they strictly the global namespace OpenGL functions?

What is the best practice for drawing on a QGLWidget from a separate class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `gl…` functions are just the regular OpenGL functions, or if a extension wrapper is being used the macro names resolving to the wrapper's symbols. QGLWidget takes care of OpenGL context creation and management, just like GLUT or GLFW do.

QGLWidget offers the member function `QGLWidget::makeCurrent` which selects the QGLWidget instance's OpenGL context being the current context in the thread from which `QGLWidget::makeCurrent` is called. `QGLWidget::swapBuffers` issues the double buffer swap. After you're done using the OpenGL context, say at the end of a renderer function, call `QGLWidget::doneCurrent` which will detach the context from the current thread; this is neccesary to make OpenGL work in multithreaded programs – if you make sure that all OpenGL operations are done from the very same thread, you may omit the call to `QGLWidget::doneCurrent`.

Of course in a true OOP fashion program, you should pass a reference to the other class to your derivation of QGLWidget and call that one's drawing function from the QGLWidget's drawing handler.

Comment: Just for info, `swapBuffers` is called automatically after `paintGL` returns.

Comment: Just to elaborate on the extension wrappers. Qt provides QGL/[QOpenGLFunctions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html) (also versioned as in QOpenGLFunctions_2_1) classes that will load and bind the OpenGL function pointers. The results are cached for each context. You can also directly call functions bound for a context using QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions()->gl...

Answer (score 1):

They are global namespace OpenGL functions.

Call the drawing function of the other class in the paintGL() function.

```
void MyGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    other->draw();
}
```